# Glider.js Container Same Width as Image

Tags: javascript, carousel

I'm using [www.glider.js](https://nickpiscitelli.github.io/Glider.js/index.html#demos), with a "single item":

```
new Glider(document.querySelector('.glider'), {
  slidesToShow: 1,
  dots: '#dots',
  draggable: true,
  arrows: {
    prev: '.glider-prev',
    next: '.glider-next'
  }
});
```

I'm trying to make the container the same width as the first image that was loaded, so that I don't have to supply a max-width property:

```
.glider-product {
    max-width: 250px;
    border-radius: 10%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: white;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
}
```

I've tried the following Javascript, however it doesn't seem to function on slightly older browsers:

```
// Get the first image element
var firstImage = document.querySelector('.glider img:first-child');

// Get the width of the first image
var firstImageWidth = firstImage.offsetWidth;

// Set the width of the Glider.js container to match the first image width
var gliderContainer = document.querySelector('.glider-product');
gliderContainer.style.width = firstImageWidth + 'px';
```